# Multi threading in Java, track success & failure tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, completable-future, concurrent.futures

I am trying to run a async method in scheduled for every 5 mins in Spring to process 1000 of tasks using 100 threads.At end of every run I need to figure out how many task's failed & succeeded.
I tried using Completable future using below sample code but I am facing 2 main issue.

1. If some exceptions comes schedular restarts without completing run.
2. How to get success/failure task number after run.I would like to print at the end success tasks:[1,2,4,5] failed tasks : [9,10,7,8]

```
//ScheduledTask
public void processTask(){
List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> futures=new ArrayList<>();
for(int I=0;i<300;i++){
 futures.add(service.performTask(i));
 }
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();
}
```

//MyAsyncService

```
@Async

public CompletableFuture<Integer> performTask(int i){
try{
Thread.sleep(1000);
final Thread currentThread=Thread.currentThread();
final String oldName = currentThread.getName();
**currentThread.setName(oldName+"-"+i);**
int test=(int) (i+10)/RandomNumber(0,10); // generate random number between 0 to 10 and divide I+10 by that to fail some tasks randomly.
return CompletableFuture.completeFuture(i);
}catch(Exception e){
CompletableFuture<Integer> f = new CompletableFuture<>();
f.completeExceptionally(e);
return f;
}

}
```

//MyAsyncConfig

```
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();

        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("async-thread-");
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(100);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(300);

        threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();

        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }
```

Comment: [`ExecutorService#invokeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection))?

Comment: 100 threads are highly extreme and probably cost you slower performance unless your machine(cpu) has 100+ threads. You can track your jobs by sending each job as A child of Callable interface to an executir thread pool since they return an onject called Feature that allows you to keep track of each threads status individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, I think we still need the join to wait the completion of the whole set of  CompletableFutures for the scheduled task :)

Another thing, to make sure the scheduled task finished, we need to use exceptionally() or handle() to catch the exception.

```
    public void processTask() {
        List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> futures=new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> successes = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> failures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int record = i;
            CompletableFuture<Integer> integerCompletableFuture = performTask(i).handle(((integer, throwable) -> {
                if (throwable != null) {
                    failures.add(record);
                } else {
                    successes.add(record);
                }
                return integer;
            }));

            futures.add(integerCompletableFuture);
        }
        CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();
        log.info("successes: {}", successes);
        log.info("failures: {}", failures);
    }
```

This will print something like this:

```
[main] INFO rxjava.CompletableFutureConcurrency - successes: [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
[main] INFO rxjava.CompletableFutureConcurrency - failures: [2, 8]
```

or something like this if you don't need success records.

```
public void processTask(){
        List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> futures=new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> failures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int record = i;
            CompletableFuture<Integer> integerCompletableFuture = performTask(i)
                    .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                         failures.add(record);
                         return record;
                    });
            futures.add(integerCompletableFuture);
        }
        CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();
        log.info("failures: {}", failures);
```

This will print something like this:

```
[main] INFO rxjava.CompletableFutureConcurrency - failures: [2, 8]
```

PS: Here I used the `int record = i`. You can play without it know why I did so ;)

**Updated on 26.03.2022**

The async execution of the performTask is handled by `@Async` annotations. As asked by @user3134221, if we want to use our own executors, we could use `supplyAsync` of `CompletableFuture`.

[CompletableFuture.supplyAsync](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.concurrent.Executor-)

I made a demo here (sorry, it's done in a rush, not perfect :/ ), you could check [Example of how to run performTask in different threads](https://github.com/yingkun-bai/java-concurrency/blob/main/src/main/java/concurrency/CompletableFutureConcurrency.java)

Comment: @Cherry - Thanks lot for your help. I will try to put & test this solution

Comment: @Cherry - it worked well but I ran into another issue. I am giving name to threads by setting current threadname + I , and looks like its reusing same thread and name goes on every run. Updating code

Comment: Method performTask , Line -> currentThread.setName(oldName+"-"+i);
Gives output 
async-thread-1
next run
async-thread-1-2
next run 
async-thread-1-2-3
and keeps going ..looks like it reuses same thread...how to stop reusing threads

Comment: @user3134221, could I ask why you wanna change the thread name? I updated the answer to meet you needs. In order to let performTask run async in different threads, we need to do more for that.

Comment: @Cherry - Thanks ton man...I am running schedular task for every 10 mins asynchronously & I want to track in log what every thread does in each task..hence I want to name thread with task number in it.i tried setting thread name in perform task method as (old name + task number)  but I found the its keep on increasing in every schedular run as its reusing thread.

Answer (score 2):

The call to join() on the CompleteableFuture is throwing an exception if any of the tasks failed, so that is likely the problem.

Instead of calling join, try something like this to get the counts of success / failures using the whenComplete method:

```java
    public void processTask(){
        List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> success = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> failures = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
            int rec = i;
            futures.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> performTask(rec)).whenComplete((a, ex) -> {
                synchronized (success) {
                    if (ex == null)
                        success.add(rec);
                    else
                        failures.add(rec);
                }
            }));
        }

        for (CompletableFuture<Integer> f : futures) {
            try {
                f.join();
            } catch (CompletionException ex) {
                // ignore
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Successes = " + success);
        System.out.println("Failures = " + failures);
    }

    public Integer performTask(int i) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

        int test = (int) (i + 10) / RandomUtils.nextInt(0, 10);
        return i;
    }
```

Edit: There was a problem with reporting the numbers of the failures, which I have fixed.

Edit #2: I incorrectly started whenComplete waits for completion before proceeding. That was not correct, code has been adjusted.

Edit #3: The method performTask as written in this post does not actually perform any work asynchronously. I have re-written it to be asynchronous.

Comment: Your code does not “wait for all threads to finish”. Further, `whenComplete` does not specify, which thread will execute the action, while `ArrayList` is safe for modifications by arbitrary threads.

Comment: @Holger - whenComplete does wait for the thread to finish, in fact

Comment: No it does not. I have no idea where got that idea from. `whenComplete` chains a dependent action, just like `thenApply`, `thenAccept`, or `thenRun`. Like all of these methods, you have no control regarding which thread will execute the chained action.

Comment: Whoops, you are correct. I realized what confused me about this code is that performTask is not running asynchronously, the way it's written, even though it returns a CompleteableFuture so my code was working because all the tasks were complete already.

Comment: I suppose, the `@Async` annotation is supposed to direct a framework to inject the actual asynchronous execution.

Comment: Good point. I haven't used that syntax before

Answer (score 0):

To answer the comment why same thread is reused, I think the following code is responsible as it completes the future synchronously instead of asynchronously.

```
for(int I=0;i<300;i++){
 futures.add(service.performTask(i));
 }
```

*performTask* method returns a completed future and the caller waits for the response. Hence everything is executed sequentially instead of parallelly in multiple threads.

Instead, try using supplyAsync when adding the *performTask* o/p to the collection of futures.